# How to make travis execute Angular tests on Chrome ("Please set env variable CHROME_BIN")

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, karma-runner, travis-ci

I'm working on a sample Angular project generated by yeoman.
I am able to run karma tests locally (I set system variable `CHROME_BIN` to point to chromium binary, but this could have been done in more elegant way. Just a quick work-around.)

However, when attempting to produce a successful build with travis, I get following error:

```
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
    Can not find the binary google-chrome
    Please set env variable CHROME_BIN
```

I've followed the steps described [here](https://coderwall.com/p/ndaemg)  (basically using `generator-travis-ci`)
Then tried to fix it with [this](http://lynckia.com/licode/travis-webrtc.html) - got another error:
`/home/travis/build.sh: line 142: ./.travis/scripts/install_chrome.sh: Permission denied`

It's a standard angular app created with Yeoman - things should work out of the box, whereas reality is different ...
Has anybody successfully configured it?

---

Software versions I've been using:

```
user@machine:~/somewhere $ yo -v; grunt --version; bower -v
1.0.4
grunt-cli v0.1.9
grunt v0.4.1
1.2.6
```

my Travis job: https://travis-ci.org/vucalur/editor-yeoman-test

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm afraid to say that you can only run Firefox (because it's already installed in the VM) and PhantomJS (because it's portable and headless).

Add the following into your `.travis.yml` file to startup Firefox:

```
before_install:
  - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
```

Then you'll just have to enable Firefox as a Karma browser in your configs.

[Documentation](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/)

Comment: documentation for the Firefox launcher with Karma: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-firefox-launcher

Answer (score 30):

Use this solution to get it running using the preinstalled Chromium Version in Travis-CI VM:
https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1144#issuecomment-53633076

#### .travis.yml

```
  node_js:
  - "0.10"

script: node_modules/karma/bin/karma start test/karma.conf.js --single-run

before_install:
  - export CHROME_BIN=chromium-browser
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
```

#### karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  var configuration = {

    /* ... */

    // start these browsers
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeCanary'],

    customLaunchers: {
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },

    /* ... */

  };

  if(process.env.TRAVIS){
    configuration.browsers = ['Chrome_travis_ci'];
  }

  config.set(configuration);
};
```

Comment: This answer needs to have the solution and steps to implement it rather than a link to the answer. The link could break in the future.

Comment: It appears that this solution no longer works due to changes in the travis-ci VMs to OpenVZ.

Answer (score 7):

Based in karma-runner project issue (https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1144#issuecomment-53633076) You should set `CHROME_BIN` environment variable in your `.travis.yml` and configure a customLauncher in your karma file configuration.

For example, your .travis.yml file content will be:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
    - '0.10'
before_script:
    - 'export CHROME_BIN=chromium-browser'
    - 'export DISPLAY=:99.0'
    - 'sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start'
    - 'npm install -g bower karma grunt-cli jshint'
    - 'npm install'
    - 'bower install'
```

And your `karma.conf.js` content:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        // ... your default content

        // This is the new content for your travis-ci configuration test
        //  Custom launcher for Travis-CI
        customLaunchers: {
            Chrome_travis_ci: {
                base: 'Chrome',
                flags: ['--no-sandbox']
            }
        },

        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
        singleRun: true 
    });

    if(process.env.TRAVIS){
        config.browsers = ['Chrome_travis_ci'];
    }

};
```

Answer (score 4):

### Option 1: APT Addon

You can make Travis execute Angular tests in Chrome by using the [APT Addon](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/#Installing-Packages-with-the-APT-Addon) to install the `google-chrome-stable` package and run it headless using Xvfb.

```
# Set language
language: node_js

# Set version of node
node_js:
  - node

# Set DISPLAY for Xvfb
env:
  - DISPLAY=:99.0

# Use APT Addon to install Chrome
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - google-chrome
    packages:
      - google-chrome-stable

# Start Xvfb so you can run headless Chrome
before_install:
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start

# Install packages
install:
  - npm install

# Run tests in continuous integration mode
script:
  - ng test --single-run
```

### Option 2: Chrome Addon

Alternatively, if your [virtualization environment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/overview/#Virtualization-environments) is Linux Trusty or OS X you can use the Chrome addon in headless mode.

```
# Use a trusty version of linux
dist: trusty

# Set language
language: node_js

# Set version of node
node_js:
  - node

# Install Chrome addon
addons:
  - chrome: stable

# Install packages
install:
  - npm install

# Run tests in continuous integration mode with headless chrome
script:
  - karma start --single-run  --browsers ChromeHeadless
```

To run e2e tests, update `protractor.conf.js` to specify headless chrome.

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',

  chromeOptions: {
     args: [ '--headless', '--disable-gpu' ]
   }
}
```