# Chromedriver on Travis-CI

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, travis-ci

I am having trouble getting chromedriver on Travis-CI working for my project [knockout-secure-binding](http://github.com/brianmhunt/knockout-secure-binding). I am trying to use WebdriverJS to automate testing with Chrome, at the least.

[I noted](https://github.com/brianmhunt/knockout-secure-binding/issues/2) that there seems to be some issues with chromedriver on Travis-CI, including:

- http://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/938
- http://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/272
- https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=308

The issue seems to be a variant of "chrome not reachable", and from what I can gather it requires an upstream engagement by Google to fix it.

The details of the error are [available through the Travis build log](https://travis-ci.org/brianmhunt/knockout-secure-binding).

No workaround is apparent, though one comment mentioned using `--no-sandbox`, but it is not clear where or how one would employ this in WebdriverJS.

Any thoughts on this would be sincerely appreciated.

### —— Edit ——

As a matter of interest I am using [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/) in lieu of Chromedriver.

Comment: Try adding `sudo: true` to your `.travis.yml` file. That will start a different type of VM which might work better. (The boot time will be slower, though.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an easier way to launch Chrome on Travis CI, simply specify google-chrome in addons/apt/sources and google-chrome-package in addons/apt/packages.

Here's my sample config for a better understanding:

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - google-chrome
    packages:
      - google-chrome-stable

language: node_js
node_js:
  - "6"
cache:
  directories: node_modules
branches:
  only: master

before_script:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
  - npm i -g npm@^3
  - sleep 3
```

Answer (score 4):

I think Travis does support chrome driver, if you add these in your travis.yml, extract the right chromedriver and unzip it to a known location, so that you can trace it later.

```
before_script:
  - wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.10/chromedriver_linux64.zip
  - unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/
  - export CHROME_BIN=chromium-browser
  - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  - sleep 3
```

Plus when you call selenium or any testing automation library, you would need to add this the code here is in `Python` but this can be done in `Java` and `Ruby` as well.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'
#All the arguments added for chromium to work on selenium
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") #This make Chromium reachable
options.add_argument("--no-default-browser-check") #Overrides default choices
options.add_argument("--no-first-run")
options.add_argument("--disable-default-apps") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9   /chromedriver',chrome_options=options)
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** As of October 2018, Travis CI is slowly moving away from containers (see [official announcement](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-10-04-combining-linux-infrastructures)). Therefore, one can omit `sudo: false`, but the given ChromeDriver setup still works.

<s>If you want to use a [container-based](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/overview/#Container-based) environment (fast boot time but no `sudo`),</s> you can also do it as follows (include `language` and so forth accordingly):

```
dist: trusty
sudo: false

addons:
  chrome: stable
  apt:
    packages:
      - chromium-chromedriver

before_script:
  # include ChromeDriver in PATH
  - ln --symbolic /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver "${HOME}/bin/chromedriver"
  # start Chrome and listen on localhost
  - google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost &
```

Afterwards, as you already mentioned, add `--no-sandbox` to your Chrome options (taken from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/anandsunderraman/e351485319a8a0e7df7e)):

```js
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var chromeOptions = {
    'args': ['--no-sandbox']
};

var chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', chromeOptions);

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities).build();
```

This is due to an [issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8836/) in Travis CI. However, if you need `sudo` anyway or have a long-running build where a container-based environment makes only limited sense, you can also set `sudo: true` and omit adding `--no-sandbox`.

Additional resources:

- [Google Chrome addon on Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/chrome/)
- [GUI and headless browser testing on Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/)
- [How to make travis execute Angular tests on Chrome ("Please set env variable CHROME_BIN")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19255976/3429133)