# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException because of "Chrome version must be >= 64.0.3282.0" although version is 65.0.3325.181 on Travis CI

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, travis-ci, jboss-arquillian

While I was attempting to extend [Arquillian PrimeFaces](https://github.com/omnifaces/arquillian-primefaces)'s `.travis.yml` with a setup for `phantomjs` and `chromeheadless` browser driver for functional tests with Selenium, I experienced

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create statement
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to instantiate Drone via org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver(Capabilities): org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 64.0.3282.0
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Linux 4.4.0-101-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 564 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
System info: host: 'travis-job-bdbf5b81-b2fa-4377-b5de-da7743f04986', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-101-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 64.0.3282.0
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Linux 4.4.0-101-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 564 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
System info: host: 'travis-job-bdbf5b81-b2fa-4377-b5de-da7743f04986', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-101-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

So, I updated `chromium-browser` with `sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-dev && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --yes chromium-browser` and verified that it's the only Chrome binary and has a matching version with `which -a chromium-browser && chromium-browser --version` which reveals that the only binary is `/usr/bin/chrominum-browser` and has version 65.0.3325.181. However, the error persists.

I researched and found issues with Chrome on Travis CI like

- https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/938 which is about permissions (as opposed to versions)
- [Chromedriver on Travis-CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364674/chromedriver-on-travis-ci) which summarizes issues

and checked [the Arquillian web driver configuration options for Chrome](http://arquillian.org/arquillian-extension-drone/#webdriver-configuration) which don't seem to include one to expose the actual pick up of the ghost 64.x binary.

An example run of the failure can be found at https://travis-ci.org/krichter722/arquillian-primefaces/jobs/364342730.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you have mentioned about using **Chrome v65.0.3325.181** but the error stack strace shows different versions as follows :

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 64.0.3282.0
```

This essentially means *ChromeDriver* is unable to detect the right version of **chrome** binary. It appears you either have installed multiple instances of *Chrome* Browsers and have multiple instances of *chrome* binaries within your system or there are multiple stray instances of *chrome* binaries available within your system.

### Solution

- You must ensure that **Chrome** is installed at the optimum location as the server expects you to have *Chrome* installed in the default location for each system as per the snapshot below :

[image: chrome_binary]

**Note** : For Linux systems, the *ChromeDriver* expects `/usr/bin/google-chrome` to be a symlink to the actual Chrome binary. You can also override the Chrome binary location following the documentation [Using a Chrome executable in a non-standard location](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Using-a-Chrome-executable-in-a-non-standard-location).

- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.