# Run travis - karma tests on multiple browsers?

Tags: karma-runner, travis-ci

Normally it is possible with Karma to run my tests on multiple browsers. Is it possible somehow to run the same tests on Travis?

As far as I know Chrome needs some modifications on the travis config file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25661593/607033

Do these modifications interfere with other browsers (e.g. Firefox, Opera, Msie, PhantomJS, etc.) I want to run on travis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come up with the following karma.conf.js file:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    var options = {
        plugins: [
            "karma-browserify",
            "karma-chrome-launcher",
            "karma-firefox-launcher",
            "karma-ie-launcher",
            //"karma-opera-launcher",
            "karma-phantomjs-launcher",
            "karma-mocha"
        ],
        ...
        browsers: [
            "Chrome",
            "Firefox",
            "IE",
            //"Opera",
            "PhantomJS"
        ]
    };

    if (process.env.TRAVIS) {
        options.customLaunchers = {
            Chrome_travis_ci: {
                base: 'Chrome',
                flags: ['--no-sandbox']
            }
        };
        options.browsers = [
            "Chrome_travis_ci",
            "Firefox",
            //"IE",
            //"Opera",
            "PhantomJS"
        ];
    }

    config.set(options);
};
```

and the following .travis.yml:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "5"
before_install:
  - export CHROME_BIN=chromium-browser
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
```

The Internet Explorer is working only by Windows environments, so it is not supported by Travis (because it uses Linux). The karma-opera-launcher has serious bugs, so I wasn't able to use it by Travis and on Windows. According to the github page of the plugin it should work on Linux, but I did not want to spend more time on it.

So the modifications don't interfere with each other, because only Chrome requires modifications and those are contained by a custom launcher. All of the non-PhantomJS browsers require display and xvfb in the .travis.yml.

Another possible solution would be to use SauceLabs, but this testing is not critical to me, so I don't want to pay 250$/y for it.